# Walking through different directories, but collections.Counter values are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm using the collection.Counter function to create a dictionary of paths to its listing of its mime types in order. It's a great little module, however the Counter doesn't change it's values from path to path.

I have a dictionary called package_mime_types that each entry looks like this:

```
 package_mime_types['/a/path/to/somewhere'] = [('text/plain'),('text/plain'),('application/msword')]...
```

As you can imagine, the values in that dictionary are very long. I'm trying to convert it to a listing like this:

```
package_mime_types['/a/path/to/somewhere'] = ['text/plain':780, 'application/msword':400, 'audio/mp3':30]
```

This is my little iteration that's supposed to do that:

```
    for package_path, mime_types_list in package_mime_types.items():
        c = collections.Counter(mime_types_list)

        package_mime_types[package_path] = c
    return package_mime_types
```

The end result works, but all the Counter arrays are the exact same for each path.

```
/path1/ relates to Counter({'text/plain': 2303, 'audio/x-wav': 90, 'text/html': 17,       'application/msword': 17, 'application/x-trash': 6, 'application/x-tar': 4,    'application/xml': 1, 'text/x-sh': 1})
/path2/ relates to Counter({'text/plain': 2303, 'audio/x-wav': 90, 'text/html': 17, 'application/msword': 17, 'application/x-trash': 6, 'application/x-tar': 4, 'application/xml': 1, 'text/x-sh': 1})
/path3/ relates to Counter({'text/plain': 2303, 'audio/x-wav': 90, 'text/html': 17, 'application/msword': 17, 'application/x-trash': 6, 'application/x-tar': 4, 'application/xml': 1, 'text/x-sh': 1})
/path4/ relates to Counter({'text/plain': 2303, 'audio/x-wav': 90, 'text/html': 17, 'application/msword': 17, 'application/x-trash': 6, 'application/x-tar': 4, 'application/xml': 1, 'text/x-sh': 1})
/path5/ relates to Counter({'text/plain': 2303, 'audio/x-wav': 90, 'text/html': 17, 'application/msword': 17, 'application/x-trash': 6, 'application/x-tar': 4, 'application/xml': 1, 'text/x-sh': 1})
```

Am I missing something with using the Counter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facepalming myself right now. It wasn't a problem with the Counter at all but rather the iteration I was doing to create the listing of the file types. I didn't make a new array each time the iteration was populating my dictionary. So all of the files were associated with each path.

```
def find_mimes(package_paths):
package_mime_types = {}
mime_types_list =[]
## Walking through directories looking for the mime types
for package_path in package_paths:


    print(package_path, "is being walked through")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(package_path, followlinks = True):
        for file in files:
            if mimetypes.guess_type(os.path.join(root, file)) != (None, None):
                mime_types_list.append(mimetypes.guess_type(os.path.join(root, file))[0])

    package_mime_types[package_path] = mime_types_list
```

See how mime_types_list is above the iteration? It was a static variable. Moving into the package_path loop fixed it.

```
def find_mimes(package_paths):
package_mime_types = {}

## Walking through directories looking for the mime types
for package_path in package_paths:
            ##Setting mime_types_list array back to empty for every path. (Duh)
            ##Now mime_types_list will be empty before the walking starts

            mime_types_list =[]


    print(package_path, "is being walked through")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(package_path, followlinks = True):
        for file in files:
            if mimetypes.guess_type(os.path.join(root, file)) != (None, None):
                mime_types_list.append(mimetypes.guess_type(os.path.join(root, file))[0])

    package_mime_types[package_path] = mime_types_list
```

Comment: Python identifiers are NOT variables ans lists are NOT arrays. It's a pitfall many have to realize coming from a C-background! I like to call python's identifiers "tags" or "label", they are more like untyped references/pointers then variables!

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm switching daily from PHP to Python. It's hard to keep them straight.

Comment: Btw.: That's a good opportunity to point to advert to the problem of toooooo deep nesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity So, keep your units small. More functions! ;_)